# Can I use single handler to display toast and alter dialog Box?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

I wish to use the toast in order to provide feedback message to user based on operation.
Since I am performing the operation on Non UI thread I understand that it is not possible to update **Main Thread** from this **Non Main Thread**,so am using **handler** to perform my operation.
Can I use the same **handler** to display the different toast message through out the program.
Can I use the same **handler** to perform the dialog box operation or should I use different **handler** for that.
Which would be more feasible?

Can some one guide me ??

Comment: You can use N number of toast and dialog in handler, use Message object send different messages to the handler.

Comment: @rajahsekar: Thanks for that comment.Should i use different handler to perform toast and dialog box or using one can I perform both the operation.

Comment: Use one handler to perform both